Break out data from one row to multiple rows on Google Sheets
I am currently building a sheet to collect data from an online form and need to have individual records for each division a person is in.
The data comes in like this:



ID Number
First Name
Last Name
Div 1
T-Class 1
Class1
Div 2
T-Class 2
Class 2




99
John
Doe
BB

Master
Physique

open


98
Mary
Smith
Bikini

Open





97
Mark
Lawson
Trans
>100

Fit Physique

Teen



I would like the records returned as:



ID Number
First Name
Last Name
Division
T-Class
Class




99
John
Doe
BB

Master


99
John
Doe
Physique

Open


98
Mary
Smith
Bikini

Open


97
Mark
Lawson
Trans
>100



97
Mark
Lawson
Fit Physique

Teen



I have used this to get the results:
=FILTER({A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,D2:D,E2:E,F2:F;A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,G2:G,H2:H,I2:I},LEN({A2:A;A2:A}))
The issue I have is this will be expanded to 6 divisions and this will return 6 records even if they have only entered one division.
I only want the record if the "Division *" has data.
Sample Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X96cMz-b6RVhgJ5-k130QQq-vpwYLG_Tbr0EII805bQ/edit?usp=sharing

One approach is to stack the columns and then remove any rows where there is no ID or no Div. You can fine-tune the conditions based on your data.
QUERY Version
=SORT(
   QUERY({A2:F;A2:C,G2:I},
     "Where Col1 is not Null AND Col4 is not Null"))

QUERY  SORT
FILTER Version
=LET(
   rng,{A2:F;A2:C,G2:I}, 
   FILTER(rng, LEN(INDEX(rng,,1)), LEN(INDEX(rng,,4))))

FILTER  INDEX  LEN  LET
LAMBDA Version
If you want to be able to vary the number of sets without much hassle, this version lets you define the number of sets of {Div,T-Class,Class} you have in s.
=LET(
   i,A2:C, s,6, r,COUNTA(A2:A),
   d,WRAPROWS(TOROW(OFFSET(i,,3,r,s*3)),3),
   FILTER({SORT(MAP(SEQUENCE(r*s), LAMBDA(x,
     INDEX(i,IFERROR(1/(1/MOD(x,r)),r))))),d},
     LEN(INDEX(d,,1))))

COUNTA  FILTER  IFERROR  INDEX  LAMBDA  LEN  LET  MAP  MOD  OFFSET  SEQUENCE  SORT  TOROW  WRAPROWS

The identification columns are stored in  i
s holds the number of sets to look for in your data
The row count is stored in r
d holds the actual sets data:

OFFSET returns the columns and rows starting 3 columns from column A with a height equal to r and a width equal to s*3. If there are 6 sets then s*3 equals 18 columns.
TOROW transforms the sets to a single row
WRAPROWS transforms the row to a 3-column array.


A SEQUENCE of numbers from 1 to r*s is created. where r*s represents the maximum number of rows there could be based on the populated rows and the number of sets.
MAP passes the sequence one by one into a LAMBDA that stores the current value in x
The LAMBDA's formula uses MOD to return the remainder of dividing x by r.  If this was used simply to return an array, it would be a sequence of numbers number from 1 to r-1 followed by 0 repeated s times. INDEX uses the result of MOD to retrieve one of the rows from i after first dividing 1 by the inverse of that result which will trigger an error if MOD returns 0 but leaves all other numbers unchanged, in this way 0 is replaced by r using IFERROR..
Once the last value passed in by MAP has been processed by the LAMBDA, the resulting array is sorted back into the original order by ID Number and then combined with the d and combined array is filtered to remove any rows where the first column of d was not populated.

